# asp.net MVC3 validation default color is showing as black instead of red

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3. I have a basic project which was working fine and showing the default MVC validations as red.

Now the validations, although still functional, are showing as Black instead of Red. Everything works fine apart from that.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Research", 
            new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, 
            new { @class = "form"}))
    {


                <div style="margin-top:20px">
                  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                  <div class="input">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)                
                  </div>
                  <div class="input">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                  </div>              
                </div>

                <div>
                  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                  <div class="input">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)                
                  </div>
                  <div class="input">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="actions" style="margin-bottom:20px">              
                  <input type="submit" value="Log On" class="button" />
                </div>

    }
```

Comment: Try adding below line in your page:  `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 2):

In default site css file change following classes:

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color: Black;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

include `~/Content/css` in your layout