# Red coloring of the MVC validation errors is gone. They're in black

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

The validation errors in my MVC project are showing up in black instead of the default red. Everything else works fine.

Just like this guy reported, but hasn't found a resolution yet:

[asp.net MVC3 validation default color is showing as black instead of red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258602/asp-net-mvc3-validation-default-color-is-showing-as-black-instead-of-red)

The CSS file has the color as red.

Comment: have you inspected the element using browser tools to see what styles are actually applied?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I just checked in Developer Tools in IE. There are no styles being applied. Strange. The _layout file has the Styles.Render method call with the proper bundle name. The bundleconfig has the proper Include and the Global.asax has the BundleConfig registered.

Answer (score 0):

Leading on from the comments it looks like the class is not being applied to the element or your css is not loading correctly.

Can you verify each independently.  View source and check your bundled reference and that it actually includes the style sheets you require.